# why am I always getting count of radio buttons in a page as zero?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the count of radio buttons with name="preferred_color". I always get count = 0. What am i doing wrong? There are 6 radio buttons on the page "http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm" with that name.

Below is the code:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class RadioButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm");

        Thread.sleep(4000);

        List<WebElement> radio_button = driver.findElements(By.name("preferred_color"));

        System.out.println(radio_button.size());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, where name are also exists for any other elements, try to use cssSelector or xpath. In ur html there also exist iframe, so you need to switch to iframe first like below:

```
driver.switchTo().frame( driver.findElement( By.cssSelector( ".result[name = 'result1']" ) ) );
```

Now use the below code:

```
List<WebElement> radio_button = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(" form>input[name = 'preferred_color']"));
```

You need to tell the exact element locator to get element or elements.

U need to switch to another iframe to get the other radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the webdriver won't go search in iframe. And in that page, it seems that every radio buttons are in `iframe`...

After navigating to page, try to do

```
driver.switchTo().frame("resutl1");
```

"resutl1" being the name of the first `iframe`.

It will print "3".